# Why I cannot use the anonymous method like that?

Tags: c#, delegates, anonymous-methods

Why can't I have this? I mean it would spare a delegate declaration:

```
int X=delegate int(){...};
```

I know it can be done this way:

```
delegate int IntDelegate();
...
IntDelegate del=delegate(){return 25;};
int X=del();
```

Comment: Have you looked at this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yw3tz5k(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 5):

A delegate is not an int.

If you use .Net 3.5 or newer you can use the built in Func instead of using a custom (Func also have generic types if you need arguments like Func which tages a string and return an int):

```
Func<int> X = delegate() { return 255; };
```

or with lambda expressions:

```
Func<int> X = () => 255;
```

Unfortunately, you can't say:

```
var X2 = () => 255;
```

in C# but you can do something similar in functional languages ex F#. Instead you would say the following in C#:

```
var X2 = new Func<int>(() => 255);
```

Answer (score 2):

Tomas,

would this work for you:

```
    delegate int IntDelegate();
    // other stuff...
    IntDelegate _del = () => 25;
```

jim

[edit] - oops, just realised, the question was re making it a one liner!! - i'll have a think

Answer (score 2):

Because in the first example, you're trying to assign a delegate type into an int, rather than the output of a delegate into an int. A delegate is a type that stores a function, which just so happens to return a value that you're interested in.

Answer (score 2):

Is there really a need for creating a delegate, executing it, and returning the value?
Why not just execute the code directly?

```
int x = new Func<int,int>(num => num*num) (3);
```

would return 9, but so would:

```
int x = 3*3;
```